# ARC Semantic Issue When Installing Firebase Using Cocoapods

Tags: swift, firebase, xcode9.2

I'm trying to install Firebase onto my existing project using cocoapods. I have followed the instruction from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iMkifTEaefE) official video. I followed the everything step by step and when i tried to open the app.xcworkspace and build the project, I'm getting an error

> Google Data Transport ARC Semantic Issue

I've tried removing the entire pod from the project and try again but none of it worked. I'm using xcode 9.2

These are the content of my Podfile

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.2'   

target 'LittleThinker' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for LittleThinker
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
end
```

This is the error message that I'm getting [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pw0F.png).

What seems to be there issue here? Anyone able to assist?

Comment: May be you should specified a version of `Firebase/Auth` and `Firebase/Firestore` in your podfile. Because you're using XCode 9.2 and your podfile configure latest version of `FIrebase` so I think you should find a compatible version of `Firebase` and set it into your podfile like -> `pod 'Firebase/Auth', 'x.x.x'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update Xcode.

The current Firebase version requires at least Xcode 10.1. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup

Comment: Thank you sir did not see that requirement as i was following older videos on youtube